# Use DNS server if available in DnsMasq

Tags: dnsmasq

I've got a PiHole DNS server installed on my local network at IP 192.168.1.x.

When I'm at work with my laptop, I can't use my home wifi's DNS server. Is there any way to configure PiHole to use my home DNS server if available or fallback to other IPs if not?

Here's my current config:

```
no-resolv
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

It looks like the way it uses those is round-robin for now.